# How can I change the bootstrap font include urls from relative to absolute when using the Aurelia cli

Tags: javascript, gulp, aurelia

I'm building a application using Aurelia and the Aurelia cli. Using the workaround described [here](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/248#issuecomment-243483842) I'm able to copy the fonts from bootstrap to the correct location (/bootstrap/fonts) and it works as expected when loading the root of the site. The paths in bootstrap.css will however all be relative (bootstrap/fonts) which means that when I load any other url, lets say "/products", the fonts will be loaded from "/products/bootstrap/fonts" where they obviously wont be found. Is there any way I can change the urls in bootstrap.css when building with the Aurelia cli? I would just like to add "/" in front of any url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add bootstrap resources (css and fonts) manually to `index.html` file and add new build stage to `build.js` file instead of `aurelia.json` config file.

[You can find code example for font-awesome here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271458/how-can-i-add-font-awesome-to-my-aurelia-project-using-npm/39544587#39544587) (bootstrap files will be have the same code).