# How to bundle/use binary resources that your dependency has in AureliaJS?

Tags: aurelia, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use SemanticUI with AureliaJS (CLI version) and in my aurelia.json file I've added

```
{
    "name"      : "semantic-ui",
    "path"      : "../vendor/semantic-ui/2.2.4",
    "main"      : "semantic",
    "deps"      : ["jquery"],
    "exports"   : "$",
    "resources" : [
        "semantic.css"
    ]
}
```

which seems to be bundling the semantic.js and semantic.css files.

What do I do with the images and fonts that are referenced in semantic.css file?

The vendor-bundle.js file generated by `au build` is in scripts folder and so the paths no longer work ok to load those images/fonts file.

Comment: You need to create a gulp task that copies those images over to wherever you're distributing your files. The CLI just uses Gulp under the hood. This is exactly what we're doing now with our setup.

Answer (score 0):

Aurelia can't process font or images files (only js and css). You must use manual bundle task for complex libs.

Here is similar solution for font-awesome: [How can I add Font Awesome to my Aurelia project using npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271458/how-can-i-add-font-awesome-to-my-aurelia-project-using-npm/39544587#39544587)