# How to support multiple i18n endpoint in Aurelia?

Tags: i18next, aurelia

I made a plugin library called [Aurelia-Slickgrid](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid) and I'm looking at adding [i18n](http://aurelia.io/docs/plugins/i18n/) to support multiple locales. I got it all setup and working in my own development environment but then once I have it all bundled and everything, how will the user use the locale that I created (from `node_modules/aurelia-slickgrid/locales`)? Will the user have to copy & paste the keys/values that I created? I only have a dozen keys or so, not that big of a deal but still, I would rather use them directly.

The current setup that I have is like this

```
import { I18N, TCustomAttribute } from 'aurelia-i18n';
import * as Backend from 'i18next-xhr-backend';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-i18n'), (instance) => {
    instance.i18next.use(Backend);

    return instance.setup({
      backend: {
        loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}.json',
      },
      lng: 'en',
      attributes: ['t', 'i18n'],
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      debug: false
    });
  });
}
```

I know that I can add the `{{ns}}` in the play but I don't think that will help me. The problem is more around, how can I add another endpoint? If I add `ns` like this

```
loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json', // <-- XHR settings for where to get the files from
```

It still comes from the same endpoint. So the question is really about, how to handle multiple backend endpoints/paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the consumer of your plugin will have to bundle his app somehow as well. So having any references to node_modules is definitely not the way, since those files won't be available when accessing the prod app, without the presence of a node_modules folder.

This scenario is pretty much the same as [bootstrap and using their custom fonts (glyphicons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658563/aurelia-cli-include-bootstrap-glyphicons). You would copy them over to a well-defined place (in your case ./locales) and keep the structure as it is.
Youd place them using a custom `ns` as this is exactly the reason why i18next supports multiple namespaces. So your resulting example would be something like:

```
./locales/en-US/aurelia-slickgrid.json
./locales/de-DE/aurelia-slickgrid.json
...
```

The user needs than to make sure to consume those translations using a different namespace.

Having multiple endpoints is not supported by standard translation loaders (see [here](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend/issues/155)). The reason would be that the use-case is too specific.

Comment: Hmm ok, so you're saying that is like an assets folder which has to be copied over to a centralized assets folder. So I need to use a copyFiles in my webpack config. I didn't think about that approach but it makes sense after a bundling. Thanks

Comment: Exactly, its just an asset artifact. The i18n plugin extends the default NS itself for the relative time feature to provide Default translations, so take a look at that one to see an alternative to asset Copy Basta